# Excel - How to prevent users from pasting over data validation ranges in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

How would I modify the below code to account for multiple named ranges?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Does the validation range still have validation?
    If HasValidation(Range("DataValidationRange")) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Application.Undo
        MsgBox "Error: You cannot paste data into these cells." & _
        "Please use the drop-down to enter data instead.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub

Private Function HasValidation(r) As Boolean
    'Returns True if every cell in Range r uses Data Validation
    On Error Resume Next
    x = r.Validation.Type
    If Err.Number = 0 Then HasValidation = True Else HasValidation = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The [original posting of this code on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/870926/restrict-paste-into-dropdown-cells-in-excel) answered this question: select all the cells with data validation and give a named range to the group. In this case, DataValidationRange. This will work even if the cells are part of other named ranges.

However, testing this code with an Excel 2010 workbook caused an Excel crash on my system. You'll want to have your file saved prior to testing.