# Prevent cell overlay Copy/Paste over drop-down columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, copy-paste

I have an Excel sheet that contains multiple non-contiguous drop-down columns. I can protect these drop-down columns from typing any unlisted entry thru cell validations. But I cannot protect them from cell overlay copy/paste. I used a macro from another post on this site, but that works only for one column in the NamedRange. ([Restrict paste into dropdown cells in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/870926/restrict-paste-into-dropdown-cells-in-excel/871247))

I tried to combine the NamedRanges with Union and with CombinedRange syntax and run the macro. But it doesn't work for multiple drop-down columns.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: (1) Did you actually get the answer from that other question to work?  I tried it and it failed. (Whenever I typed into any cell, the `Worksheet_Change` function called itself recursively until Excel ran out of stack; then Excel aborted.)  (2) What do you mean by “CombinedRange syntax”?  What did you try?

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4289-excel-disable-cut-copy-paste.html Is this worked for you?

Comment: @Scott -
1. Yes, it worked for me, but only for 1 col. Ex. - i have dropdowns for col E, F, G and O. When i put a NamedRange for E5:E20 & use it in the macro, it works fine. Cell overlay copy/paste is blocked. I also have generic cell validations in place to prevent typing in the dropdown cols. But when i try multiple NamedRange for E & F & use them in the macro, it goes into infinite loop & excel closes.
     
2. I used UNION - 
`Sub ColsUnion() Dim rng1 As Range Set rng1 = Union(Range("E5:E20"), Range("F5:F20")) rng1.Select End Sub`

This dont work. Same loop error & excel closes.

Comment: OK, I figured out ***my***  problem (it was a stupid error).

Answer (score 0):

I took [the answer](https://superuser.com/q/870926/150988#871247)   to
[the linked question “Restrict paste into dropdown cells in Excel”](https://superuser.com/q/870926/150988)
and adapted it for multiple ranges, and made some cosmetic changes. 
I also added a safety net to catch recursion. 
You may be able to delete
the bold/italic lines:

```
Dim WSC_Recursive As Boolean
 
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Does the validation range still have validation?
    If WSC_Recursive Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If HasValidation(Range("DataValidationRange1")) And _
       HasValidation(Range("DataValidationRange2")) And _
       HasValidation(Range("DataValidationRange3")) And _
       HasValidation(Range("DataValidationRange4")) Then
          Exit Sub
    End If
    WSC_Recursive = True
    Application.Undo
    WSC_Recursive = False
    MsgBox "Error: You cannot paste data into these cells." & vbCrLf & _
          "Please use the drop-down to enter data instead.", vbCritical
End Sub
 
Private Function HasValidation(r) As Boolean
    'Returns True if every cell in Range r uses Data Validation
    On Error Resume Next
    x = r.Validation.Type
    If Err.Number = 0 Then HasValidation = True Else HasValidation = False
End Function
```

Note: each of the NamedRanges must have validation applied to it — in fact,
it must have the same validation applied to every cell in the range. 
For example, you cannot have a range of `G17:H42`
if `G17:G42` has one type of validation and `H17:H42` has a different type
— or even if they have the same *type* (e.g., drop-down)
but different parameters (e.g., different lists of valid values).

If you have this set up and working, and you want to add a range, you should:

1. In either order,

   - define the named range and
   - apply the validation to the cells

   ***and only then***
2. add the new range to the `Worksheet_Change` routine.

In the more general case where you’re changing validation rules,
you might want to follow this procedure:

1. Rename the `Worksheet_Change` routine to something else (e.g., `Worksheet_ChangeX`).
2. In either order,

   - make your changes to the sheet, and
   - (if necessary) change the code, e.g., change

     ```
     HasValidation(Range("DataValidationRange2")) And _
     ```

     to

     ```
     HasValidation(Range("DataValidationRange2a")) And _
     HasValidation(Range("DataValidationRange2b")) And _
     ```

   and then
3. Rename the routine back to `Worksheet_Change`.

---

Personally, I believe that this code could be designed better,
but, if it works, it works.

Comment: Scott - apologies for a delayed reply. Your code works at 1st shot.   
But, if I change the `NamedRange` range or add/delete dropdown cols, the code runs into errors. Sometimes its Runtime Error `1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed when using cells`. Sometimes its an infinite loop for _Change event running the macro on itself, and it goes into every cell in the worksheet. I tried to reset 'Application.EnableEvents = False' and True, but it didnt work.
So, im still stuck :) 

Additionally, I also need to add many-to-one dependent dropdown lists for 2 cols.. uurgh :(

Comment: (1) Yeah, if one of your ranges does not have validation applied to it — in fact, if it does not have the same validation applied to every cell in the range — then the routine will blow up.  That’s an example of what I was talking about when I said that the code was designed badly.  (2) It’s really weird that you’re getting the 1004 error.  Actually, it’s normal for the *routine* to get the error, but the `On Error Resume Next` statement should prevent you from ever ***seeing*** it. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) Do you get the (infinite) loop even with my ***`WSC_Recursive`*** code?  Because (as I mentioned in my comment) I was getting the exact same problem, and the ***`WSC_Recursive`*** code fixed it. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … I have added some guidance to my answer.  If you can provide some more details about what’s going wrong, I might be able to help.

Comment: Scott - I followed your guidance, but the issue continues.
1.  I have 4 cols (as of now) with each col as each NamedRange & each has a different Data List validation.
DataValidationRangeD = 'MassUpload Estimation Templ v3'!$D$5:$D$255
DataValidationRangeE, DataValidationRangeF, DataValidationRangeG - with similar cell range.  *********
2.  I followed your instructions but infinite loop issue comes the moment a copy-paste action is triggered. Yes, I have used the `WSC_Recursive` code exactly as in the ex. *********
3. How can I share the actual xls to you ? So you can test the code on it.